# How can i remove columns which contains 0 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a table which contains suppose 4 columns i want to remove columns which contains 0 from first row to last row. In this case i want to remove 2nd & 4th column how can i achieve this using jquery

```
1   0   10  0
2   0   20  0
3   0   30  0
```

o/p should be

```
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

Comment: Does the *entire column* contain `0` or could it happen that just some cells contain `0`? Because it would break the table if you remove only some cells and leave others.

Comment: why do you need that? I think these columns contain useful data even if that data is zeros. if these columns not important so why do u bind it?

Comment: ya the entire column contains 0

Comment: columns contain 0 are useless columns i dont use those columns

Answer (score 1):

To clear all columns which consist of **only** zeros, you could first identify the 0 containing cells in first row, and for those cells, check how many 0 containing cells are in that column. If it matches total rows, then remove them.

```
var rows = $('tr').length;
$('tr:first td:contains(0)').each(function(){
    var i = $(this).index()+1;
    var s = $('tr td:nth-child('+i+')');
        if(s.filter(':contains(0)').length==rows) s.remove();


});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/frdsc/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through all the cells to check for zeros in each column, this may help:
[How to loop through table cells with jQuery and send the data to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344129/how-to-loop-through-table-cells-with-jquery-and-send-the-data-to-database)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table td")
.filter(function () {
  // cellIndex will be 0 for the first column, 1 for the second, and so on
  return (this.cellIndex == 1 || this.cellIndex == 3);
})
.remove();
```